# Why does this comparsion return false?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Double.NaN==Double.NaN return false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819738/why-does-double-nan-double-nan-return-false)

This is purely out of curiosity.

I did something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Double.NaN==Double.NaN);
    }
```

The output is `false`. Shouldn't this return `true`?

Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/):

> Floating-point operators produce no exceptions (§11). An operation
>   that overflows produces a signed infinity, an operation that
>   underflows produces a denormalized value or a signed zero, and an
>   operation that has no mathematically definite result produces NaN. All
>   numeric operations with NaN as an operand produce NaN as a result. As
>   has already been described, NaN is unordered, so a numeric comparison
>   operation involving one or two NaNs returns false and any !=
>   comparison involving NaN returns true, including x!=x when x is NaN.

The important sentence here is:

> so a numeric comparison
>   operation involving one or two NaNs returns false

Comment: and for not comparing floating point numbers for equality see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832592/test-for-floating-point-equality-fe-floating-point-equality

Comment: Good explanation. To explain it further, NaN basically mean that this number does not exist (Not a Number). Something that does not exist is equal to nothing.
In maths, for example, you DO NOT have 3/0 = 4/0 (this is Nan = Nan, basically). This does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing two Doubles better use the `#compareTo(Double)` method, it is able to handle `NaN` and `XXX_INFINITY` in a separated way.

> Compares two Double objects numerically. There are two ways in which
>   comparisons performed by this method differ from those performed by
>   the Java language numerical comparison operators (<, <=, ==, >=, >)
>   when applied to primitive double values:
>
> Double.NaN is considered by this method to be equal to itself and
>   greater than all other double values (including
>   Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY). 
>   0.0d is considered by this method to be greater than -0.0d.  This ensures that the natural ordering of Double objects imposed by this
>   method is consistent with equals.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Double d = new Double(Double.NaN);
  System.out.println(d.compareTo(Double.NaN) == 0);//returns true
}
```