# Finding a "correct" value that is unknown prior to a calculation

Tags: java, algorithm

The problem is as follows i have a large or small number (can be either one) and i need to tweak this number and put it through a caluclation. Given the result of the calulation it has to mach a certain value on the 5th decimal at least.

So i need to make a method that takes this starting value, tries to increase or decrease it given what the current result is until i get the correct result. I have made some atempts with no success.

Here is an example that won't woork at all but it hints towards what i mean... (this is just a small scale test case)

```
   public class Test {
        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            double ran = 100 + (int)(Math.random() * 100000.999999999);
            int count = 0;              
            double tmpPay = 3666.545;
            double top = tmpPay;
            double low = 0;             

            while ( tmpPay != ran )
            {
                if ( tmpPay > ran)
                {
                    if( low == 0)
                    {
                            tmpPay = top / 2;
                            top = tmpPay;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmpPay = tmpPay + ((top - low) / 2);
                        top = tmpPay;
                    }        
                }           

                if (tmpPay  < ran)
                {
                    tmpPay = top * 1.5;
                    low = top;
                    top = tmpPay;                   
                }
            }
            System.out.println(" VAlue of RAN: " +ran + "----VALUE OF tmpPay: " + tmpPay + "---------- COUNTER: " + count);         
}
```

Example 2 mabey a more clear description. This is my solution now..

```
guessingValue = firstImput;

while (amortization > tmpPV)
{
    guessingValue -= (decimal)1;
    //guessingVlue -- > blackbox
    amortization = blackboxResults;
}
 while (amortization < tmpPV)
{
    guessingValue += (decimal)0.00001;
    //guessingVlue -- > blackbox
    amortization = blackboxResults;
}
```

}

Comment: `c#` and `java`? You should pick one.

Comment: Are you trying to do a binary search?

Comment: Not really a binary search. I need to find what the in parameter should be for a calculation to get a specific answer. Think of the calculation itself as a black box.

Comment: Comparing doubles using standard java operators ==,<,> etc. is not a good idea. You can find why here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832592/test-for-floating-point-equality-fe-floating-point-equality

Comment: If the calculation is truly a black box, it's impossible - consider `if (x == 0.3433) return 1; else return 0;`. It's impossible to know when the function would return `1` here.

Comment: If trying to run the program, it will easily be in infinite loop, since the while condition could hardly equal by double values comparison. e.g. There are 2 values,  double value1 = 3666.545; double value2 = 3666.545002; value1 == value2 is false. Even this kind of values are not equal. You'd better define a range for deviation. Then, e.g,  if |value1 - value2| <0.0002, then break the while condition and print the random num information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comment above you should not compare doubles using build-in operators. This is the main reason why your code is not working. The second one is that in else clause tmpPay = tmpPay + ((top-low) /2); instead of tmpPay = tmpPay - ((top-low) /2 );

Complete fixed code is below :

```
public class Test {
    private static final double EPSILON = 0.00001;
    public static boolean isEqual( double a, double b){

        return (Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON);

    }


    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        double ran = 100 + (int)(Math.random() * 100000.999999999);
        int count = 0;              
        double tmpPay = 3666.545;
        double top = tmpPay;
        double low = 0;             

        while ( !isEqual(tmpPay, ran))
        {
            if ( tmpPay > ran)
            {
                if( isEqual(low, 0.0))
                {
                        tmpPay = top / 2;
                        top = tmpPay;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpPay = tmpPay - ((top - low) / 2);
                    top = tmpPay;
                }        
            }           

            if (tmpPay  < ran)
            {
                tmpPay = top * 1.5;
                low = top;
                top = tmpPay;                   
            }
            System.out.println("RAN:"+ran+" tmpPay:"+tmpPay+" top:"+top+" low:"+low+" counter:"+count);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(" VAlue of RAN: " +ran + "----VALUE OF tmpPay: " + tmpPay + "---------- COUNTER: " + count);




    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, good to hear i was not COMPLEATLY off target.

This will be a good example to build a solution around.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define your problem as a [local optimization task](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem) and use an local optimizer (for example Brent's method or Nelder Mead Simplex from [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optimization/direct/NelderMeadSimplex.html)).

Your goal function here would be the distance between the desired value and what you get from your black box.

Comment: Mabey that is a solution i can try and specify my problem even further and add another example in the question. ANd if this applies could u hint at how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a function g(x) and a value K, you want to find x0 such that g(x0) = K.
This is equivalent to find the roots of the function f(x) = g(x) - K, because f(x0) == f(x0) - K == K - K == 0.

A simple algorithm would be [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: Thank's for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If trying to run the program, it will easily be **in infinite loop**, since the while condition (for double values comparison) could hardly equal. 
e.g. 
There are 2 values as follows:

double value1 = **3666.545**;

double value2 = **3666.54500001**;

value1 == value2 is false.

Even this kind of values are not equal.

You'd better define a range for deviation.

e.g, if |value1 - value2| < 0.005, then break the while condition and print the random num information.