# How do you check if a list contains an element that matches some predicate?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList containing objects which have 4 parameters (x, y, iD and myType). I want to verify if there are objects in this ArrayList which have particular coordinates, independently of their iD and myType parameters. 
I wanted to use `Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourValue)` but it is when the object has only one parameter.

Here is the whole code:

```
public class MyObject {

  public float x;
  public float y;
  public int iD;
  public String myType;


  public MyObject (float x, float y, int iD, String myType) 
  {
    this.myType = myType;
    this.iD = iD;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  @Override
    public String toString() {
    return ("[iD="+iD+" x="+x+" y="+y +" type="+myType+"]");
  }
}


ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

void setup() 
{
  size(100, 60);
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject(3.5, 4.5, 6, "a"));
  myArrayList.add(new MyObject(5.4, 2.6, 4, "b"));
}
```

For example, if I want to verify if there is an object which has the coordinates (3.5, 4.5), how should I proceed ?
Is there an easy way to do this ?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ***override equals function*** to define equal:

```
public class MyObject {

    public float x;
    public float y;
    public int iD;
    public String myType;


    public MyObject (float x, float y, int iD, String myType)
    {
        this.myType = myType;
        this.iD = iD;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("[iD="+iD+" x="+x+" y="+y +" type="+myType+"]");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof MyObject) {
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
            return myObject.iD == this.iD && myObject.myType.equals(this.myType);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

***Attention:***

I must admit it's dangerous way to do this. ***override equals*** maybe will cause strange issues in program if you have used ***equals*** do some other compares. but in special case, maybe you can do that.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! And then I use myArrayList.contains((3.5, 4.5)); 
?

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick You would need to have nested `for` loops to check whether each pair of elements is "equal". Or if you already know that you are looking for (3.5,4.5) you could use `List.indexOf(Object)` to get and remove the first object and if call `indexOf` again and it returns `-1` it will mean there is only one such object while if it is a positive integer it will mean there are two objects with (3.5,4.5).

Comment: This is a bad idea. They want to use `contains`. With overriding equals, they'd have to create a new object with garbage id and type. Instead, they should iterate over each element and compare only those properties which are relevant.

Comment: @M.Shaw thanks for your help. I don't need to check if there is only one, I need to check if there is at all an object which have these coordinates or not ...

Comment: With Java 8s `Stream` and `filter` it's easier.

Comment: Having `equals` compare a subset of fields sounds dangerous

Answer (score 5):

The javadoc of [`List#contains(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) states

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element.

That's not what you're trying to do here. You're not specifying an element, you want to specify properties of an element. Don't use this method.

The long form solution is to iterate over the elements in the `List` and check them individually, returning `true` as soon as you find one, or `false` when you run out of elements.

```
public boolean findAny(ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList, float targetX) {
    for (MyObject element : myArrayList) {
        if (element.x == targetX) { // whatever condition(s) you want to check
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Since Java 8, there's a better way to do this using [`Stream#anyMatch(Predicate)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) which

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate.

Where the given `Predicate` is simply a test for the properties you're looking for

```
return myArrayList.stream().anyMatch((e) -> e.x == targetX);
```

---

Regarding equality checks for floating point values, see the following:

- [What's wrong with using == to compare floats in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java)
- [Test for floating point equality. (FE_FLOATING_POINT_EQUALITY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832592/test-for-floating-point-equality-fe-floating-point-equality)