# JAVA: Difference in Two Floats

Tags: java, floating-point

```
double double1 = 0.174;
double double2 = 0.175;
double diff = Math.abs(double1 - double2);
```

`diff` returns `0.0010000000000000009`

Now I type:

```
double double1 = 3.174;
double double2 = 3.175;
double diff = Math.abs(double1 - double2);
```

I am expecting `diff` to return the same result, but it returns `9.999999999998899E-4`.
Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Hi, see this question also. Float comparison behaves differently than integer comparison https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832592/test-for-floating-point-equality-fe-floating-point-equality

Comment: *"Is there a reason for this behaviour?"* Yes.

Comment: Floating point numbers are basically integers with a built-in scaling factor (which is also an integer), plus some other fluff (for instance, they need to be able to values such as NaN and infinity). So they are only approximate at best. When you push them to their limits, the inaccuracy shows.

Answer (score 0):

can use BigDecimal

```
        BigDecimal decimal1=BigDecimal.valueOf(1.744);
        BigDecimal decimal2=BigDecimal.valueOf(1.745);
        BigDecimal result=decimal2.subtract(decimal1);
        double diff=Math.abs(result.doubleValue());
```